How to determine which installation process I used to install an application
I use various way of installing application

apt install
snap install
.deb

But every time, when I need to update a program I struggled to find which method I use to install, therefore which method I need to use to update it.
How can I know easily know which installation method I used ?

etckeeper might be useful going forward for this kind of things (and more).

apt install downloads and and installs .deb packages. Some of those deb packages might install corresponding snaps.
That's the case for instance of the firefox package on Ubuntu 22.04 at least whose /var/lib/dpkg/info/firefox.preinst which does a snap install firefox.
Also note that a .deb package that you install locally with dpkg -i or gdebi might add an apt repository, which will make it so if updated versions are published, they will be pulled by apt.
apt policy package-name

Will give a report of where versions of the package-name deb packages are available in configured repositories, including an entry for /var/lib/dpkg/status if the package is installed.
If the installed version matches a version found in one of the configured repositories, that's a good indication that it was installed through the apt framework (except for the case mentioned above where a manually installed .deb happens to configure a new apt repository).
Conversely, if the package is not available, in any version from any repository, just showing in /var/lib/dpkg/status, or if the locally installed version is newer than any found in any repository, that's a good indication that it was installed locally. That's not a guarantee though as it could also be that that particular version was removed for a reason or other from the repository it was initially installed from, or the repository it was pulled from was later disabled/unconfigured.
To get a list of installed packages that are not found in any of the currently configured repositories, you can do:
aptitude search '~o'

(now also supported by apt list).
That doesn't show the ones that are found in repositories but with older versions for which you could do:
aptitude search --disable-columns -F '%c%M%S %p %v "%d" [%t]' '~S~i !~U !~o' |
  awk  '$NF == "[now]" || $NF == "[]"'

(the !~U is to not report the ones that are upgradable, that is for which there is a newer version available in a configured repository).
To get a list of snaps, you can do:
snap list

Or
snap list --all

To get all the revisions.
If a package does include one or more executable, then if it comes from a snap, it will be found in /snap/bin as a symlink to /usr/bin/snap.
$ type -a chromium
chromium is /snap/bin/chromium

You can tell if a file in a package comes from a .deb package (whether it was installed manually or via apt) with dpkg -S (which actually calls dpkg-query --search underneath).
Beware though that these days /bin is a symlink to /usr/bin, and some packages extra their commands in /bin, some in /usr/bin, so you'll want to check both:
$ dpkg -S /bin/firefox
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /bin/firefox
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/firefox
firefox: /usr/bin/firefox

Or do a pattern search:
dpkg -S '*/bin/firefox'

Or a substring search (when the first character of the pattern is none of *[?/) with dpkg -S bin/firefox (though that might also include things like /sbin/firefox-updater).
Here /bin/firefox and /usr/bin/firefox are the same file, but the package lists only /usr/bin/firefox as one of its member files, in the corresponding .list file:
$ grep -Fx /usr/bin/firefox /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/firefox.list:/usr/bin/firefox

Here, /usr/bin/firefox comes from the firefox .deb package but as mentioned above, the firefox software actually comes from a snap and /usr/bin/firefox is just a script that calls /snap/bin/firefox.
Other sources of information you can look at are logs:

/var/log/aptitude* for things installed/removed/updated by aptitude
/var/log/apt/history.log* for the same for apt commands.
/var/log/dpkg.log* for the same for dpkg (which is called by apt and aptitude).
journalctl _COMM=snap-store for snap things.

If you're familiar with git, using etckeeper to keep a history of the configuration of your system in a git repository helps. It might need extra configuration to work with snaps though which are a Ubuntu-only thing.
Of course, dpkg, apt* and snap are not the only ways to install software and deb/apt are not the only packaging systems available on Ubuntu. Many programming languages come with their own(s) like pip3, cargo, cpan, etc. And of course you or the administrator of your system can install software with a plain copy of the files or some custom installer, or the make install or equivalent of a source distribution in your home directory or /usr/local or /opt/vendor, etc, possibly with symlinks in /bin, /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin or elsewhere in the standard $PATH.

Generally, things get easier if you don't do things like installing .deb packages from wild sources. That's almost always a bad idea. (very very specific exceptions exist, but as a normal user you should rarely encounter them.)
Anyways, first step is to figure out where a said application actually resides. If you start it via a shell, a simple type -p {command} will show you the path to the program. If that path contains /var…/snap…, then it's in a snap.
If it's not, dpkg -S /path/to/executable will tell you which package the file is from.
And if you don't know from which repository you installed that, apt policy {package name} will tell you.
